# Positioning circle and line together for timeline

Tags: html, css

I would like to implement timeline part on my website.

I have picture how it should look but I can't think any good way to do it.

**How it should look:**

[image]

Actual code:
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gev0uquf/)

```
<div class="right ">
    what should I put here to get that circle?
</div>
```

Most confusing part is how to get that circle and that line together?

Could anyone suggest anything?

Thank you.

Comment: You dont want to use an image?

Comment: Is that good idea? I am worried because how will it look on different screen sizes...

Comment: I think it's still an acceptable method. Even if you use CSS to display the circles you still need to handle it on different screen sizes. But yeah you are right to be apprehensive about image. if you can, go with CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `:after`, changing the styles to your liking.

`.border` needs to be positioned non-statically.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1030px;
  background-color: #534741;
  height: 500px;
}
.right {
  color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
  display: block;
}
.border {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 140px 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.border:after {
  /* Position and border */
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  right: -34px; /*** -(Width+Border) ***/
  height: 32px;
  bottom: -18px; /***  -((Height/2)+Border)  ***/
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.text {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="right">
    <h2>Text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h3>2014</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="right "></div>
  <div class="right border"></div>
  <div class="right text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum doloremLorem ipsum doloremLorem ipsum doloremLorem ipsum doloremLorem ipsum dolorem</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gev0uquf/2/)

Comment: If you're adding border-radius, maybe using 50% is less error prone (less to rewrite if you ever resize the circle) otherwise this is a nice solution.

Comment: This looks good. When I change to be on the left hand side I can't get it to looks just like on this image because that JAN and 2011 are moved down, why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work:

```css
    
.box-with-circle {
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
}
.box-with-circle .circle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin -20px 0 0 -20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.box-with-circle hr {
   position: relative;
   top: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box-with-circle">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <hr />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it with positioning and borer radius. Or simply use images.

```css
.content-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.line .circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
}
.line {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.odd .line {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.even .line {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.odd .circle {
  right: -50px;
}
.even .circle {
  left: -50px;
}
.content,
.header {
  padding: 0 60px;
}
.odd .content,
.odd .header {
  text-align: right;
}
.even .content,
.even .header {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper odd">
  <div class="header">Some title</div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Loerm ipsum dolerom</div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper even">
  <div class="header">Some title</div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">Loerm ipsum dolerom</div>
</div>
```